# A question on max norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is question 30 in chapter 7  from royden

"Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in C[a, b] and $\sum a_k$ a convergent series of positive numbers such 
that  $|| f_{k+1}- f_k||_{\max} \leq a_k, \forall k$
Prove that 
$|f_{k+n}(x)- f_k(x) | \leq || f_{k+n}- f_k||_{\max} \leq \sum_{j=n}^{\infty}a_j ,\ \forall k,n  $

Conclude that there is a function f$\in$ C[a, b] such that $\{fn\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on [a, b] "

I know that, it is easy to solve this question if the series above starts from j=k , by adding and subtracting $f_{k+1},..., f_{k+n-1 } $ to the leftside and useing the triangular inequality.

But in this problem the seris starts from j=n.
I tried hard to solve it., however I have not any good idea.
Can you help me??
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a typo to me. What you say you can prove ought to be the indended meaning.

Comment: Well, the statement is not true and that's why you couldn't solve it. It looks like a typo. To see this, suppose it's true and take $n$ to $\infty$.Then we get $\lim_n f_n = f_k$ for all $k$ which is absurd.

Comment: To elaborate slightly on my first comment, as a "test" consider constant functions $f_k$ defined via $f_{k+1}(x) = f_k(x)+a_k$.

Comment: Thank you so much